# Getting error 127 when calling GetProcAddress

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I am writing a global hook for WH_GETMESSAGE. But I am getting the error code 127 i.e.,ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND, when calling the GetProcAddress function from the dll. Its unable to find the GetMsgProc. Any idea why?

Also, I am new to this kind of programming, so apologies for any mistake that's not expected.

DLL File:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("I am in"),TEXT("In a DLL"), MB_OK);

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Program Loading the DLL file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef LRESULT(CALLBACK *LPGetMsgProc)(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int main()
{
    HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(_T("../../dllTouchInputHook/x64/Debug/dllTouchInputHook.dll"));
    LPGetMsgProc proc = (LPGetMsgProc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "GetMsgProc");
    if (proc == NULL) {
        printf("The error code is %d", GetLastError());
    }

    HHOOK hMsgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, proc, hDll, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMsgHook);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't check result from `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: of course it not found `GetMsgProc` because it not exported under this name.

Comment: @DanielSęk: I did the check the result for LoadLibrary. Its not Null

Comment: @RbMm : I didn't get you. Apologies for that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @AnkeetGhosh - why you decide that `GetMsgProc` exported exactly under this name ? it is mangled. you need use def file for export with undecorated name as is instead `__declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: @RbMm: It worked. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is not being found because it is not being exported as `"GetMsgProc"` like you are expecting.  It is actually being exported more like `"_GetMsgProc@12"` (32bit) or `"_GetMsgProc@20"` (64bit) instead.  If you want it exported as `"GetMsgProc"` then you need to use a `.DEF` file when compiling the DLL.

You shouldn't be implementing the hook in this manner to begin with.  You should move the call to `SetWindowsHookEx()` inside the DLL itself, and then export a function to call it, eg:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>

HINSTANCE hThisDLL;
HHOOK hMsgHook;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    hThisDLL = hinstDLL;
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("I am in"), TEXT("In a DLL"), MB_OK);
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

__declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI InstallHook()
{
    if (!hMsgHook)
        hMsgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, &GetMsgProc, hThisDll, 0);
    return (hMsgHook != NULL);
}

__declspec(dllexport) VOID WINAPI UninstallHook()
{
    if (hMsgHook)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMsgHook);
        hMsgHook = NULL;
    }
}
```

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPInstallHook)();
typedef VOID (WINAPI *LPUninstallHook)();

int main()
{
    HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(_T("../../dllTouchInputHook/x64/Debug/dllTouchInputHook.dll"));
    if (!hDll)
    {
        printf("The error code is %d", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    LPInstallHook installProc = (LPInstallHook) GetProcAddress(hDll, "InstallHook"); // or "_InstallHook"
    LPUninstallHook uninstallProc = (installProc) ? (LPUninstallHook) GetProcAddress(hDll, "UninstallHook") : NULL; // or "_UninstallHook"

    if (!(installProc && uninstallProc))
    {
        printf("The error code is %d", GetLastError());
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!installProc())
    {
        printf("The error code is %d", GetLastError());
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        return -1;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    } 

    uninstallProc();

    FreeLibrary(hDll);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"_GetMsgProc@20" (64bit) instead.* - no, x64 not decorate names. on x64 it will be exported as `GetMsgProc` if it written on *c* or declared with `extern "C"` otherwise will be complex *c++* name

Comment: @RbMm: it actually depends on the compiler used. What you describe is what Microsoft's compiler does (by default, but it CAN mangle names in 64bit as well - case in point, even YOU said in another comment that the name is being mangled, even though the code is clearly loading an x64 DLL). Other compilers are not required to (and rarely do) follow what Microsoft does

Comment: if we programming for windows - we need use windows *lib* files from sdk/wdk for statically linked with windows api. as result how compiler mangle *c* names must be exactly matches to corresponded *lib* file - otherwise we got error - unresolved external symbol. for example must be `_ReadFile@20` for x86 and `ReadFile` on x64. exactly. we some compiler  use another name conversion - it will be incompatible with windows lib files

Comment: *even YOU said in another comment that the name is being mangled* - yes it will be mangled as any *c++* name

Comment: @RbMm: "*if we programming for windows - we need use windows lib files from sdk/wdk for statically linked with windows api*" - actually, you don't, but let's say for argument's sake that you do (because I don't want to argue it). "*as result how compiler mangle c names must be exactly matches to corresponded lib file*" - yes, but static link lib files are specific to the compiler/linker toolchain being using, so they are not required to follow Microsoft naming schemes (and many 3rd party toolchains do not). Besides, Win32 APIs are not exported from their DLLs using mangled names to begin with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for the above mentioned code. In the install hook function of your code, you have passed the HINSTANCE variable hThisDll as an argument to SetWindowsHookEx. I know that this variable was declared globally but for some reason, the compiler is unable to figure that out. Although, its able to recognize it in the DllMain function. Any idea why?

Comment: @AnkeetGhosh sounds like you might have declared it locally instead of globally

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Its alright. I don't expect you to spoon feed everything. Thanks for your help